# Is it a good practice to let my website users use the built in orchard admin page to add content

Tags: content-management-system, content-type, orchardcms, content-management

I wanna let my website users add content, do I have to build a module? or use the Custom forms module or just use the built in admin page "http://mysite/Admin/Contents/Create/"
and if yes, shouldn't I hide the admin panel from my end users?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you care if somebody changes your whole website to a Viagra ad?

Comment: u missed understand that dude... He's got limited permissions to only create the appropriate content

Answer (score 1):

Use custom forms. That's what it's for.